# Laravel eloquent sort by most duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel eloquent query which filters duplicate entries in `field` and returns the unique values sorted by timestamp.

```
$test = $this->myModel
    ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('field')
    ->get();
```

Instead of just 'filtering' the  duplicates, I would like to count them and return the data ordered by the count of each duplicates.

Also is it possible to return the actual count numbers with the data or must I use two different queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the groupBy'd field and sort by that count.

```
$test = $this->myModel
    ->select('my_models.*', 'COUNT(field) as fieldcount')
    ->orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('field')
    ->sortBy('fieldcount', 'desc')
    ->get();
```